# How to select a property of a macro parameter in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, umbraco

This is a very basic XSL question and I am just getting started with the topic in the context of Umbraco:

I've defined a macro with a XSLT file. The macro has a parameter of type 'ContentPicker'. What I want to do with the macro, is to render the picked content in a certain way. The relevant bit of my XSLT file is this:

```
<xsl:param name="source" select="/macro/BlogPostSource"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<div>
    <xsl:value-of select="$source/blogPostIntroduction"/>
</div>
```

I define a parameter, which is set to the parameter of the macro (this works). Now I simply want to render the property `blogPostIntroduction` which is a generic property on the picked content. This doesn't work. If I use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$source"/>
```

the ID of the content is rendered.

**Question A: How do I select fields of the selected content?**

**Question B: Is my idea correct in general or am I missing a better way to do what I need, rather than using macros and XSLT?**

Comment: If you use `<xsl:copy-of select="$source" />` to output the full contents of `$source`, what do they look like?

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for getting back to me. The output of the copy-of command is the id of the selected content as well: 2200 ;)

Comment: @Mark - Are you displaying that in a browser? If so, could you do View Source and see if it's actually just 2200 or actually a bit of XML?

Comment: Hi again, you're right! It sais: <blogpostsource>

    2178

</blogpostsource>